# how to sum variable static values in while or for loop?

Tags: php, variables, sum

is that possible to `sum variable static values` in the while or for loop? i have code and working on it but it `sum variables` only one time?

**For Example I want Like This**

i need to sum `b values` with every results?

**Here My Code**

```
<?php 
$a='10';
$b='20';
$i=0;
while($i <=10)
{
$c=$c=$a+$b;
$i++;
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $c[$i] ?>" />
<?php }?>
```

Comment: I dont understand it you want to sum 10+20 10 times? isnt same as (10+20)*10 ?

Comment: @GGio yes if `$c=10+20=30` then `$c=30+10+20=60' i want this this ?

Comment: Why loop? can't you just do `($a+$b)*$i` ?

Comment: how long does this continue if 30 then 30+10+20, then if 60 then 60+50+40+30+20+10 .... ? how long

Comment: Thats what I was thinking...what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @baig772 what do you mean by `$i`? i dont understand?

Comment: @gigo it should goes until `loop end`

Comment: @user2419956 `$i` means how many times you want to multiply them

Comment: @baig772 thanks friend i got to put `
$c = 0;`

Comment: @user2419956 my answer below also states the same

Comment: accept the answer also :)

Comment: @baig772 i need to sum `b values` with every results?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple loop

```
$a = '10';
$b = '20';
$c = 0;
$t = 10;
while($t --) {
    printf("<input type=\"text\" value=\"%s\" />", $c += $a + $b);
}
```

Comment: I dont think thats what he wants :D

Comment: @GGio what do you think he wants ?

Comment: see my answer i think thats what he wants

Comment: Like i said .. he does not need any loop

Comment: he needs to print input element each time

Comment: @GGio i need to print `b values with every result`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$a='10';
$b='20';
$c = 0;
$i=0;
while($i <=10)
{
$c=$c+$a+$b;
$sum=$c+$b;
$i++;
?>
```

Set `$c` to some value and then add

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $a = '10';
  $b = '20';
  $c = '0';
  $i = 0;
  while ($i <= 10) {
     $c = (int)$a + (int)$b + (int)$c;

     //your html input element with the value of c
     echo '<input type="text" value="' . $c . '" />';

     $i++;
  }
```

when `$i = 0` your result would be `10 + 20 + 0 = 30`  and input element has value **30**

when `$i = 1` your result would be `10 + 20 + 30 = 60` and input element has value **60**

when `$i = 2` your result would be `10 + 20 + 60 = 90` and input element has value **90**

etc...